# MySQL Before delete trigger to update the same row before deleting

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms, database-trigger

I would want to create a BEFORE DELETE trigger which can update the row before it deletes.

For example, I have below sample row in the table

```
Sno . Name . Isdelete
1 .   Ramya .  No
2 .  Ramya . No
3 .  Noah . No
```

So when I send a DELETE statement like this one: DELETE FROM TABLE where Name='Ramya'; I want to update Isdelete column to be updated to 'Yes' before actually deleting the data. I want to do something like this below with a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE DELETE
   ON Sampledata_new FOR EACH ROW SET OLD.isdelete = 'yes';
```

But this throws an error : Error Code: 1362. Updating of OLD row is not allowed in trigger. Is there a workaround to achieve that.

Note: This use case may not make sense to some but I am replicating selective data to a different target and trying to filter out data some using this strategy.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The error code pretty much tells you everything. You cannot use a trigger to modify the table the trigger is on; and your use case makes no sense; even if you could update the isDelete field, the row is gone by the end of the trigger so nothing would ever see the change.

Comment: @Uueerdo Yes I understand the error. I have given a sample of what I'm trying to achieve here. If there is a work around to achieve this please help me. My use case is to use AWS DMS to replicate data from Mysql to Redshift. In Mysql I want to retain only 6 months worth of data and delete the rest. Where as in DMS i don't want any deletes to propagate. There is no direct way to achieve that in DMS without involving any other services. So by updating the Isdelete column,I can make use of column filters in DMS I can exclude the deletes to propagate to Redshift part of CDC replication set up.

Comment: @Uueerdo The use case works perfectly fine with a separate update and delete.. I'm just trying to build a more sophisticated approach with less handling parts. Any suggestions from your end is welcome! Appreciate your feedback!

Comment: Maybe you could do a trigger on "Update" - if isdelete is set to 'yes' on Update then Delete the row? Or you have to keep isdelete in a separate table.

Comment: Yeah, If I do not get a better workaroud I may end up having Isdelete column on a different table. Thank you for your suggestion @GratusD.

Comment: @Ramya I think I see a bit more what/why you are doing what you are doing. A stored procedure _might_ accomplish what you want, but a trigger can't do what you want, and even if it allowed such operations, I would worry the replication server still would never see the updated isdelete value.

Comment: @Uueerdo That is a valuable suggestion! Yes, may be instead of directly trigerring the delete, I can call a SP to perform a two step operation. Your answer makes perfect sense.

Comment: If you are relying on that row being replicated with the updated isdelete value before the delete actually occurs, I would definitely double-check thoroughly to make sure that still occurs; unless AWS DMS hooks into the table with it's own trigger-like constructs, the reduced latency of a single procedure call (vs two queries sent separately) could cause problems.

Comment: Another option, if you do not need the rows to be deleted immediately, would be to only set the isdelete flag; and use the MySQL Event scheduler to run a query that actually deletes the rows later, at a specified time.